# Cascade delete on one to one does not work

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am using EF and Code First.

I have a Transaction class like this:

```
[Table("Transacties")]
    public class Transactie
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)] 
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string KIMTransactieCode { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string BovenliggendeKIMTransactieCode { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BovenliggendeKIMTransactieCode")]
        public Transactie BovenLiggendeTransactie { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DatumLaatstBekeken { get; set; }

        public bool? IsZichtbaar { get; set; }

        public DateTime? IsZichtbaarGewijzigdOp { get; set; }

        public OpnameInfo OpnameInfo { get; set; }
}
```

The relation is as follows:
A transaction can have a subtransaction, when there is subtransaction a reference is required to the parent transaction ('BovenliggendeKIMTransactieCode'). This is complete defined in one class/table.

It uses mainly data annotations.

I want to have a cascade delete on this class: when the (parent) transaction is deleted, all the related subtransactions must be deleted also.

I tried to invoke cascade delete as follows:

```
var transactions = mailboxDataContext.Transacties
                .Where(tr => tr.BovenliggendeKIMTransactieCode == null &&
                             tr.IsZichtbaar.HasValue &&
                             !tr.IsZichtbaar.Value &&
                             tr.IsZichtbaarGewijzigdOp.HasValue &&
                             tr.IsZichtbaarGewijzigdOp.Value < selectionDateTime)
                .ToList(); // Materialize

            if (transactions.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var transaction in transactions)
                {
                    mailboxDataContext.SetDeleted(transaction);
                }

                mailboxDataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
```

but then I get:

> "The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE
>   constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.Transacties_dbo.Transacties_BovenliggendeKIMTransactieCode\".
>   The conflict occurred in database \"PROGISKIM_Mailbox\", table
>   \"dbo.Transacties\", column 'BovenliggendeKIMTransactieCode'.\r\nThe
>   statement has been terminated."

How can this be fixed ?

**Update:**
When I try to delete the main row in SSMS I get this exception also...